# Sitecore REST API search By Navigation Category

Tags: api, rest, sitecore

I am working on building a REST API based connector to a marketplace which uses sitecore. I have found the documentation for using the search API command here:
https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/sitecore_search_and_indexing_sc60-65-a4.pdf

I have been unable to figure out how to use it to search for content that is grouped into a navigation category, and was unsure if there was a good way to do this. I did not design the site, and the designers were contractors who are no longer working with us.

I would like to be able to find a list of items based on a specific navigation category that has been assigned to them. I have tried getting the children of the category ID itself, but that did not work. Here is a picture of the navigation category associated with a given object in case it adds clarification:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKA6f.png)

Is there an easy way to search for items like this?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore? That documentation is for a much earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the assumption that you are on 7.2 or above, you just need to search for items that have the ID of the Navigation Categorization field (in your index as navigation_categorization) that are set to the ID of the item you wish to filter on. In your image, it would be the ID of "connectivity services" item.

```
var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("master").CreateSearchContext();
var computedLanguage = Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo.Name;

// get the iBuild items
var results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
   .Where(i => i["navigation_categorization"].Contains([connectivity services ID])
   && i.Language == computedLanguage)
   .GetResults()
  .Hits.Select(x => x.Document.GetItem(
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dnstommy, but I am attempting to do this via REST API call from an external source, not inside Sitecore itself. Because of this I do not have any of the classes you are referencing, which I assume are internal to Sitecore setup. The goal would be to build a call such as HTTP GET to "hostSite.com/sitecore/......." which will return a list of items with their ids and some information associated with them, similar to the regular get based on id or children of a content location.

Comment: How about an api to sitecore api? Or directly call sql. Which is not recommended, but may solve your problem.